# typeahead not updating field

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

I am trying to implement typeahead for a city look-up for, but the field does not get updated. The city details show up, but I need to show the name in the city when a city is clicked, but when the form is sent, I need to send only the city code.

This is my HTML:

```
<input id="_hotelCity" class="form-control typehead" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter city name or code " />
```

And this is the javascript:

```
$('#_hotelCity').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        airports = [];      
        map = {};
        var data = (function () {
            var data = null;
            $.ajax({
                'async': false,
                'global': false,
                'url': 'http://localhost/imakeway/forms/finder/iata-aero-codes.json',
                'dataType': "json",
                'success': function (jdata) {
                    data = jdata;
                }
            });
            return data;
        })(); 

        $.each(data, function (i, airport) {
            map[airport.complete_location] = airport;
            airports.push(airport.city + ' ( <b>' + airport.iata_code + '</b> - ' + airport.airport_name + ') near ' + airport.complete_location);
        });

        process(airports);    
    },
    updater: function (item) {
        selectedairport = map[item].complete_location;
        selectedairport = map[item].iata_code;
        return item;
    },
    matcher: function (item) {
        if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
    },
    sorter: function (items) {
        return items.sort();
    },
    highlighter: function (item) {
        var regex = new RegExp( '(' + this.query + ')', 'gi' );
        return item.replace( regex, "<strong>$1</strong>" );
    },
});
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: What version of typeahead.js are you using? typeahead.js doesn't have an "updater", "matcher", "sorter" or "highlighter" option.

Answer (score 0):

HTML `input` tag can have only one value. This value is stored internally and displays inside the field.

It seems you are using some kind of AJAX form submission.
So, your solution is to have separate variable in JS to store city code.

Another solution is to use Select2 instead of typeahead.
This is my choice when you provide a SELECT-like field but need external AJAX data source.
Btw, with Select2 you can also force user to choose only an existing value.

Look here for example: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#ajax

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use an additional `hidden` field which you update aside the normal input field.

```
<input id="_hotelCity" class="form-control typehead" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter city name or code " />
<input type="hidden" value="" name="city_code" />
```

In this hidden field you put the city code eachtime the typeahead is updated. When submitting the form your server side script can parse it (in PHP it would `$_POST['city_code']`).

Answer (score 0):

Using typeahead, and didnt want to replace very much of your code. I ended up with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ydtq9/2/

You will definitely want to refactor some things but the trick is to set some instance variables in the source function, and you can access them in the updater function like so

```
$("#_hotelCity").typeahead({
  "source": function(query, process) {
    this.map = ...
  },
  "updater": function(item) {
    var city = this.map(item)

    //Then you can do what you need to with the original data.
  }
})
```